# Кольцевой односвязанный список C#

Tags: c#, .net, структуры-данных, односвязный-список, linked-list

Необходимо было реализовать кольцевой список. Сделал через методы расширения. Но есть один нюанс. Как реализовать возврат из метода первого значения в узле? В данном случае у меня возвращается при первом проходе всегда второе значение ("Таня"), потом после последнего узла, переход к первому значению.

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Создадим связный список
        LinkedList<string> linkedList = new LinkedList<string>();

        // Добавим несколько элементов
        linkedList.AddFirst("Вася");
        linkedList.AddFirst("Петя");
        linkedList.AddFirst("Таня");
        linkedList.AddFirst("Коля");

        // Отобразим элементы в прямом направлении
        LinkedListNode<string> node;



        Console.WriteLine("Элементы коллекции в прямом направлении: ");

        for (node = linkedList.First; node != null; node = node.Next)
            Console.Write(node.Value + "\t");

        Console.WriteLine();

        var result = GetValue(linkedList.First);

        Console.WriteLine($"+++++++ {result} ++++++++");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static string GetValue(LinkedListNode<string> node) 
    {
        node = CircularLinkedList.NextOrFirst(node);
        return node.Value;
    }
}
```

Extension метод для односвязного списка:

```
 public static class CircularLinkedList
{
    public static LinkedListNode<T> NextOrFirst<T>(this LinkedListNode<T> current)
    {
        return current.Next ?? current.List.First;
    }

    public static LinkedListNode<T> PreviousOrLast<T>(this LinkedListNode<T> current)
    {
        return current.Previous ?? current.List.Last;
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы же сам написали `CircularLinkedList.NextOrFirst(node);`, так у Коли есть Next, который Таня, потому вы видите Таню вместо Коли

Comment: Да, я это понимаю и я так сделал что бы получить следующий узел, мне надо сделать какое-то условие, что бы сначала из метода возвращал First, а потом только уже Next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У метода `GetValue` неправильное название:

```
private static string GetNextCircularValue(LinkedListNode<string> node) 
{
    node = CircularLinkedList.NextOrFirst(node);
    return node.Value;
}
```

Возможно, Вы хотели сделать следующее:

```
private static string GetValueAndAdvance(ref LinkedListNode<string> node) 
{
    string result = node.Value;
    node = CircularLinkedList.NextOrFirst(node);
    return result;
}

node = linkedList.First;
var result = GetValueAndAdvance(ref node);
```

Comment: Ваш ответ абсолютно не относится к заданному вопросу. И никоим образом его не решает.

Comment: @JDo очень даже относится. Вам ответили, что за код вы написали. А что за код вам был нужен?

Comment: @JDo Для проникновения в суть моих ответов над ними следует помедитировать ).

Comment: Благодарю! `string GetValueAndAdvance(ref LinkedListNode<string> node);` На данном этапе работает идеально!

Answer (score 0):

Так как в данном коде

```
private static string GetValue(LinkedListNode<string> node) 
{
    node = CircularLinkedList.NextOrFirst(node);
    return node.Value;
}
```

сначала получается следующий элемент, а только потом берется значение, при передаче первого элемента значение будет получено у следующего.

Для решения, достаточно передавать не первый элемент, а последний:

```
var result = GetValue(linkedList.Last);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это тоже хорошее решение!!! Сразу не смекнул вчера :)

Comment: @JDo, вместо получения значение, лучше было сделать получение следующего элемента,  а значение получать через обычное свойство `Value`

Comment: @JDo, ну и раз уже сделал extensions, стоило использовать его как: `node = node.NextOrFirst();`

Comment: Это через Linq?

Comment: @JDo, причем тут linq?